# Post List <int> in http Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I want to send a data like this :

```
{
    "ad_title": "test",
    "year": "2019",
    "class": "Highline",
    "files": [ 212]
}
```

To api in flutter. I tried to do that

```
var data = {
        "year": selectedYear,
        "class": _classController.text.toString(),
        "files": json.encode(carfilesids),
    };

     final response = await http.post(url, body: data,headers:  
      {'Accept': 'application/json'});
```

However there's no errors in run time and when I print the value of json.encoder.convert(carfilesids) it gives me List, I got a response status code of 422 and it tells me " {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"files":["The files must be an array."]}} ". I also tried to json.encode the whole data but it goes wrong with the other data attributes.

Comment: The problem came from your server, check if it read the data in the right way.

Comment: you need to JSON encode data as well.
replace body parameter from `body: data` to `body: json.encode(data)` and no need to `json.encode` `files`.

Comment: I tried to add json.encode for both files and data but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You must use `jsonEncode` on your map, or else the `http` package will treat it as form data.

From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/post.html):

> If `body` is a `Map`, it's encoded as form fields using `encoding`. The content-type of the request will be set to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`; this cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

```
final response = await http.post(url,
  body: {
    "ad_title": "test",
    "year": "2019",
    "class": "Highline",
    "files": [ 212 ]
  },
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Also, consider tidying-up your code format.